# Macbook not turning on

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, nvram

My MacBook air 2015 was lid turned down for more than a month
When I opened the lid, it had 12% battery and I put it on charging and send an email to myself
After I came back it is blank and not turning on, it shows charging and nothing else
Only for the fact that on pressing control, shift, option then power button, charging indicator shows fully charged green then back to orange charging state

My question: Is my mac fine and how to make it working again?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it went away and came back again

We sent it to apple care in another state and found it to be corrupted logic board, they repaired and its as good as it can be

Comment: Thanks for coming back and supplying an answer!